# onchange event doesn't bubble in MSIE. Where do I find a chart listing all such events

Tags: javascript, events, dom

I just found out that onchange event does not bubble in MSIE. I hopped to http://www.quirksmode.org/ to see if I could find other events which are not supported by IE. However I do not see any chart listing onchange event as an event that does not bubble in MSIE. Where can I find such a char?

Comment: can you show us some code you are using for onchange event?

Comment: onchange wouldn't bubble, because the elements above/below (depending on your POV) don't change. when you click, you're clicking on a whole stack of elements, hence the bubble - not so for change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, MSDN is quite [explicit about their implementation not bubbling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536912%28VS.85%29.aspx) (unsurprisingly, doing complete opposite of what [DOM Level 2 Events module](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-htmlevents-h3) specifies).

I'm not sure why PPK table [claims bubbling as untestable](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/change.html) in IE. Could be an oversight on his part.