# OnChange not firing in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I wish to fire a Onchange event for all the changes of Form elements within a DIV

Here's the snippet

```
<html>
<body>

<div id="container">
    <input type="checkbox"/>
    <input type="checkbox"/>
    <input type="text"/>
    <input type="text"/>
</div>

<script>
di = document.getElementById("container");
di.onchange = function(a){
alert("On Change Called");
}

di.onclick = function(a){
 alert("On Click Called");
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The event is fired, when a focus is lost from any of the form elements to a new element of the form, when some content is updated (eg: the input box is updated)

The above code works fine for all browsers' but not for IE, any way to do this is IE

Comment: I do recommend using jQuery to avoid these cross browser issues, but that does not mean you should skip testing. [Jquery on Change reference here.](http://api.jquery.com/change/) Scott Leberknight's on onChange
[http://www.nofluffjuststuff.com/blog/scott_leberknight/2005/04/onclick_versus_onchange_in_ie_and_firefox](http://www.nofluffjuststuff.com/blog/scott_leberknight/2005/04/onclick_versus_onchange_in_ie_and_firefox)

Comment: possible duplicate of [onchange event doest not bubble in MSIE. Where do I find a chart listing all such events](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552689/onchange-event-doest-not-bubble-in-msie-where-do-i-find-a-chart-listing-all-suc)

Answer (score 12):

Actually, IE, especially IE7/8 doesn't support `onchange` event very well . I do recommend you use `onclick` event.

Answer (score 5):

`onchange` event [does not bubble in IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536912%28VS.85%29.aspx) according to MSDN.

Comment: This link does not reference MSDN anymore, it appears to point to Mozilla's own docs, which claim that the onChange event is supported in Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 2):

Avoid using **.focus()** or **.select()** before **.change()** function of **jquery** for IE, then it works fine, im using it in my site.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem in Edge and fixed it using an EventListener.

My code looked like this:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="my_id" name="my_name" placeholder="my_placeholder" onchange="my_function(this.value.trim())" autofocus>
```

Then I changed it to:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="my_id" name="my_name" placeholder="my_placeholder" autofocus>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById("my_id").addEventListener("change", function() {
    my_function(this.value.trim())
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Mostly all web developer must have faced this issue..
yeh the older version of IE sometimes not firing the `onChange` event and replacing it with `onClick` works.

But this is not expected with latest IE 11. what I found in my case was the function name being called on `onChange` event was clashing somewhere. I just changed it to some other name which should sound like unique in the whole context, then it worked.

> Conclusion:  IE 11 getting confused when finds some similar names
>   within the system matching with the `onchange` target function (even
>   the file names I guess), while the other browsers are intelligent
>   enough.

Comment: In my case, my dev machine running on Windows 10 + IE11(KB3203621), onchange triggered perfectly. But when I deploy it to production, testing done on Windows 7 + IE11(KB2841134), onchange refuse to work. But somehow onKeyPress did work on both dev machine & production environment. Could it be related to those update version?

Comment: @mutanic yeh.. most probably.. they have fixed this but in latest version.

Answer (score 1):

I created this code to trigger the onchange event not triggered by Interenet Explorer.

Used with an asp.net textbox

```
<!-- LOCAL SCRIPT -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

  // CTRL - fix explorer bug for OnChange not triggered. Converted to OnBlur + test
  if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer')
  {
    var tempControl = $("#<%= textboxNAME.ClientID %>");
    var tempATTRIBUTE = "data-lastvalue";
    // GET - save current value inside attribute
    tempControl.attr(tempATTRIBUTE, tempControl.val());
    // BIND - onblur event
    $("#<%= textboxNAME.ClientID %>").blur(function () {
        var tempPrevValue = tempControl.attr(tempATTRIBUTE);
        // CTRL - is there a difference of value (onchange)
        if (tempControl.val() != tempPrevValue) {
            // SET - trigger change js binded to textbox
            $(this).change();
        }
        });
  }


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually Onchange does not work very well in IE. Here is what I did while using Javascript. You can replicate it accordingly.

1. Add ondrop event in HTML to call the function being called now, instead of onchange.
2. Add the following code in your js file

   ```
   document.getElementById('--your selector--').ondragover = handle;

   function handle(evt)
   {
        evt.stopPropagation();
        evt.preventDefault();
        evt.dataTransfer.dropEffect = 'copy'
   }
   ```
3. The ondragover will be made false by above code, and then ondrop will fire on all browsers and call the required function