# jquery autocomplete selection not working on Windows Phone

Tags: jquery, windows-phone-8, onchange

I have the following input tag associated to a jquery autocomplete list. When a user starts typing in the textbox, a few autocomplete suggestions come up under the textbox. With an iPhone or Android device, a user just taps on these suggestions and the onchange event fires. But, with a windows phone, the user has difficulty selecting any autocomplete suggestion. And onchange event is never called.

NOTE:  I am mainly targeting handheld smartphones

Here is the code for the input tag

```
    <input type="text" id="AIR_CC_ADDRESS_COUNTRY_TXT" class="inputField width100" value="${value_AIR_CC_ADDRESS_COUNTRY_TXT}" onChange="updateCountry();" onfocus="searchFieldOnFocus_PURC('AIR_CC_ADDRESS_COUNTRY_TXT');" onblur="searchFieldOnBlur_PURC('AIR_CC_ADDRESS_COUNTRY_TXT');"/>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: It could be being pedantic (which wouldn't surprise me with a MS browser).  Change `onChange` to `onchange` and see if that helps.

Comment: possible duplicate of [OnChange not firing in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10876152/onchange-not-firing-in-ie)

Comment: @JonathanNaguin: The other question was IE specific (im guessing on a browser), where my site works fine. But on a touch device with IE (windows phone), i see this issue.

Comment: @Archer: I will try the change and get back. Thanks!