# how to trigger onchange event of element with javascript in IE without jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I need to trigger onchange event of an `input` with JS. Right now I'm using this:

```
document.getElementById("myElement").onchange();
```

but it seems that IE can not execute that. I know i can trigger it with jQuery, but in this project i cant use it. Is there any other ways to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10876152/onchange-not-firing-in-ie

Comment: In IE8 and below you'd normally use the `onpropertychange` event instead

Comment: this is not a solution in my case. I cant change elements in DOM i just can affect them with JS.

Comment: @BeNdErR Your link is useless. The OP says he is not able to use jQuery.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in IE use fireEvent

```
document.getElementById("myElement").fireEvent('onchange');
```

for IE9+ use dispatchEvent

```
if(document.fireEvent) {
    document.getElementById("myElement").fireEvent('onchange');
} else {
    var event = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
    event.initEvent("change",true,false);

    document.getElementById("myElement").dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: That was a nice one but still does not work in IE8 and prev.

Comment: Can You make a fiddle with example code?