# IE does not fire up on change event

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have problem with firing up `on change` event in IE. All what I have tried is working In other browsers like Chrome, Mozilla, Safari, Opera... but not in IE 11

Here is my code

*html*

```
<form method="post" id="exchangeType" action="/orders/vesselExchange">
...
<label id="deliveryDateTitleLabel" for="deliveryDate"><?= __('First time') ?></label><br/>
                <label class="radio radio-inline m-r-20">
                  <input type="radio" name="deliveryDate" value="asap" checked>
                  <i class="input-helper"></i>
                  <?= __('First time') ?>
                </label>

                <label class="radio radio-inline m-r-20">
                  <input type="radio" name="deliveryDate" value="custom">
                  <i class="input-helper"></i>
                  <?= __('Second time') ?>
                </label>
...
</form>
```

*jQuery*

```
$('#exchangeType input').on('change', function() {
  console.log('in function');
  let option = ($('input[name=deliveryDate]:checked', '#exchangeType').val());
  let dateTimePicker = $('#showPicker');

  if (option === 'custom') {
    dateTimePicker.removeClass('hidden');
  }

  if (option === 'asap') {
    dateTimePicker.addClass('hidden');
  }
});
```

What I have tried until now

```
$(document).on('change','#exchangeType input' ,function(){
...
}

$(document.body).on('change','#exchangeType input' ,function(){
...
}

$('#exchangeType').on('change','input[name=deliveryDate]',function(){
...
}
```

same functions with '`click`' (not change)

I have read and implement some answers of similair questions on stackoverflow:

- [Jquery select change not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19194177/jquery-select-change-not-firing)

- [.val() doesn't trigger .change() in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3179385/val-doesnt-trigger-change-in-jquery)

- [OnChange not firing in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10876152/onchange-not-firing-in-ie)

But it doesnt work...

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OnChange not firing in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10876152/onchange-not-firing-in-ie)

Comment: try `$("body").on("change", "#elementID", function(){
 //code here  });`

Comment: @BobSwager question is not duplicated. I have already tried with solutions from that question and it doesnt work, also that duplicated question doesnt have an answer.

Comment: @N.Ivanov I have tried but it doesnt work (in Chrome, Mozilla and Opera works, but not in IE)

Comment: @JohnWayne have you tried clearing your browser cache and reloading the javascript by clicking `Ctrl+F5`? Maybe the js hasnt refreshed.

Comment: @N.Ivanov Yes, I have, actually this is bug on live system (reported by few users).

Comment: Have you managed this problem, because I'm in the same shose, please?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes onChange event does not work with IE. You can try other event to achieve the same. Use keyup instead. Hope this helps!

Here you have radio buttons so you can use like this, example is given below:

```
<input type="radio" name="namehere" value="1" onclick="handleClick();" onchange="javascript:yourmethod()"/>

function handleClick()
{
 this.blur();  
 this.focus();  
}
```

Comment: I have tried with on click, but it is the same, also I do not need 'keyup' function because users mostly click on this option with mouse

Comment: I have updated answer for your radio button, I don't understand why its downvoted.

Comment: Onclick event is written first because for radio button it doesn't make sense to fire onchange event because radio button not get focused. Once its clicked you can call onchange event to accomplish you requirement. (For IE this changes will work too, otherwise your implementation will work (but not on IE :) ) )

Answer (score 0):

Since this does not work in IE, you could do something like this:

```
var previousFormState = getFormState();
setTimeout(function() {
    var formState = getFormState();
    if (differs(formState, previousFormState)) {
        handleChange();
        previousFormState = formState;
    }
}, 1000);
```

There are a lot of `function`s used here, I believe you can implement them, but the algorithm is to periodically test whether the `form` state has changed and if so, handle the change. You will need to make sure you execute this one last time before you `submit` the form, using the `.submit()` handler.